# cp cannot stat to ~/ in script

Tags: bash

I am having a problem I just can't seem to get over in my bash script.
Whenever I try to copy using `cp` to home folder in a script I get

```
cp: cannot stat '~/file.txt': no such file or directory
```

My code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "file location"
read a
user inputs ~/file.txt
b=$(basename $a)
cp "$a" . /$b
```

Please help, it's probably a simple solution but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: I want to be able to use a variable, I can't use ~/ instead of /home/user ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Filename expansion isn't applied to variables, which can be checked with the following minimal example:

```
d="~"; ls $d
ls: cannot access ~: No such file or directory
```

Use the full path: `/home/youruser/file.txt`.

Alternatively, you can force the globbing with `eval` (but prefer not to.. it's eval..):

```
d=$(eval echo "$d")
echo $d                  # /home/user
```

Better alternative from [@Jahid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30437357/9269177), use `$HOME` instead of `~`. So,

```bash
d="$HOME"
echo $d
```

Comment: I've decided to use Eval,  it will only be used expressly to get the user home path from ~/ I fully expect problems somewhere down the line but I couldn't get readlink to work as required :s

Answer (score 2):

You can just replace the `~` with `$HOME`:

```
read a
a=${a/\~/$HOME}
```

Now `~/file` will become `/home/user/file`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
expanded_path=$(echo "$d" | "s:^~:$HOME:")
```

(that is, subtstitute the initial `~` for `$HOME` manually)

or force the user to use the full path.
`eval` is evil (definitely for user-supplied input, it is).
If you just want to copy in the current dir while keeping the original name, you can do:

```
cp "$src" .
```

No need to play with `basename`.